# IF condition to run procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a if statement that if locked=0 then it should execute below procedures and if locked=1 then it should not execute below procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateForecast]
    @ScenarioName VARCHAR(255),
    @FiscalMonthID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@FiscalMonthID = (SELECT TOP 1 FISCALMONTHID 
                          FROM ForecastPeriodLock 
                          WHERE locked = 0 AND [STATUS] = 'Close' 
                            AND FiscalMonthId = @FiscalMonthID 
                          ORDER BY FiscalMonthId)
        AND (@FiscalMonthID != 0)) 

        PRINT @FISCALMONTHID;

    PRINT @ScenarioName;

    BEGIN
        EXEC [dbo].[usp_Backup_Tables]

        EXEC SMIStaging.[dbo].[LoadSMIFinancePlanDataToSMIForecastOpCoOpex] 
             @ScenarioName = @ScenarioName, 
             @fiscalmonthid = @FiscalMonthID

        EXEC SMIStaging.[dbo].[LoadSMIFinancePlanDataToSMIForecastOpCoPeriods] 
             @ScenarioName = @ScenarioName,
             @fiscalmonthid = @FiscalMonthID
    END

    PRINT @FISCALMONTHID;
    PRINT @ScenarioName;
END

--EXEC [dbo].[usp_UpdateForecast] @ScenarioName='AOP Plan', @fiscalmonthid=202001
```

Comment: OK, so what's the problem you have here? What's stopping you from achieving your goal?

Comment: it is executing procedures even when locked =1

Comment: Because your `IF` will simply run `PRINT @FISCALMONTHID;` if True, and won't if not. Your `BEGIN` should be **after** the `IF`, not 2 (`PRINT`) statements after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your if condition with `Begin`

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateForecast]
@ScenarioName VARCHAR(255)
,@FiscalMonthID INT

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    IF (
    @FiscalMonthID=(SELECT TOP 1 FISCALMONTHID FROM ForecastPeriodLock WHERE locked = 0 AND [STATUS]='Close' AND FiscalMonthId=@FiscalMonthID ORDER BY FiscalMonthId)
    AND     
    (@FiscalMonthID != 0) 
    ) 
BEGIN
    PRINT @FISCALMONTHID;
    PRINT @ScenarioName;

        EXEC [dbo].[usp_Backup_Tables]

        EXEC SMIStaging.[dbo].[LoadSMIFinancePlanDataToSMIForecastOpCoOpex] @ScenarioName=@ScenarioName, @fiscalmonthid=@FiscalMonthID

        EXEC SMIStaging.[dbo].[LoadSMIFinancePlanDataToSMIForecastOpCoPeriods] @ScenarioName=@ScenarioName, @fiscalmonthid=@FiscalMonthID
    END
        PRINT @FISCALMONTHID;
    PRINT @ScenarioName;
END
```